# How to make a button do a method that isn't in MainPage

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a button in MainPage that i want to execute a method that exists in another class (Shelf.cs)

I tried doing click="local:Button_click" (local = using:Shelf) , it did not let me and kept wanting to add a "new event handler"

Button in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="AddBookButton" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="675,0,0,0" click="Button_click"> // this creates a new method inside MainPage
```

method in Shelf.cs:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel adddialog = new StackPanel
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            Width = 484,
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft
        };
        TextBox title = new TextBox
        {
            Header = "العنوان:",
            PlaceholderText = "عنوان الكتاب",
            Width = 156,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 8, 0),
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft
        };
        TextBox author = new TextBox
        {
            Header = "المؤلف:",
            PlaceholderText = "مؤلف الكتاب",
            Width = 156,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 8, 0),
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft
        };
        TextBox publisher = new TextBox
        {
            Header = "الناشر (اختياري):",
            PlaceholderText = "ناشر الكتاب",
            Width = 156,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft
        };

        adddialog.Children.Insert(0, title);
        adddialog.Children.Insert(1, author);
        adddialog.Children.Insert(2, publisher);
        ContentDialog addFileDialog = new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = "أضف بيانات الكتاب الجديد",
            Content = adddialog,
            PrimaryButtonText = "إضافة",
            CloseButtonText = "إلغاء",
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft,
            Width = 700
        };
        ContentDialogResult result = await addFileDialog.ShowAsync();

        if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            Book book = new Book()
            {
                Title = title.Text,
                Author = author.Text,
            };
            try
            {
                book.Publisher = publisher.Text;
            }
            catch { }
            Books.Add(book);
            AddBookButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I Make it go to the method in shelf.cs? or possibly route the event there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `Shelf` class in the `MainForm` class and then call the `Shelf::ShelfMethod`. Names are my names - see example code below. My laptop can't do `UWP` yet (need to upgrade to Windows 1809), but here is a `Winforms` example. I think the basics of instantiating a class and calling a method are probably the same in both

On the form, add a `button` named `objButton` and a `textbox` named `objTextBox`

I named the form class `MainForm`

I named my project `CallOtherClassMethod`

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallOtherClassMethod
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainPage());
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallOtherClassMethod
{
    public partial class MainPage : Form
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ObjButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Shelf objShelf = new Shelf();
            objTextBox.Text = objShelf.ShelfMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

**Shelf.cs**

```
namespace CallOtherClassMethod
{
    class Shelf
    {
        //Constructor (does nothing in this example)
        public Shelf()
        {
        }

        public string ShelfMethod()
        {
            return "Text sent by Shelf::ShelfMethod";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i think i got it. so basically calling the method in the seperate class in MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

if im understanding what you are trying to say, you cant really do what your trying to do (to the best of my know how)... however, you can make the button click method in the mail file, call another method in a seperate class file.

if im wrong in understanding what you are asking, then could you please explain further?

Comment: i think you got what i want. you're saying that i make the method in MainPage call the method already written in Shelf.cs

Comment: Yeah exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

The most correct and best way to do this (and other things) is dividing the project into three layers, by creating a MVVM pattern and using massively data binding.

You create an AppViewModel class (which implements INotifyProperyChanged), you create a field for it in the MainPage.cs, you declare also the MainPage class as a static field, using it as a “shell” for the entire application... and you’re good to go: in the AppViewModel you can implement or reference to all the other namespaces.

Best regards